# Is it possible to have the Corruption and the Crimson Biomes in the same world?

Tags: terraria

I was reading on the wiki how there is a chance that the Corruption will be replaced with the Crimson.

I am wondering if when you get a world where you have the Crimson is it possible to also have the Corruption if you bring over corruption seeds from another world and use them. Or would these seeds just get you more of the Crimson?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

World spawn only makes one or the other, but I have made artifical corruption biome using seeds on a world with crimson.

Comment: Can you summon an Eater of Worlds on this imported Corruption?

Comment: As long as there are enough corruption blocks to change the music/background, you can summon the eater of worlds there.